# package creation file doesnot take value from .bashrc file

Tags: python, bash, wxpython, debian, subprocess

I am newbie to python, and for GUIs, I use wxpython.

My Issue is this:

I have to create a debian file for two types of products(say product 1 and product 2).That can be done by running README.package.creation file. For "product1" in ".bashrc" we have to change

```
                Product = product1
```

After that we have to do "make clean" in new terminal(otherwise changes in .bashrc will not take effect i.e "product" may not be equal to "product 1" if we dont follow the procedure), then we have to run ./Readme.package.creation.process. In Readme.package.creation then it takes automatically product type as "product 1"
If I does this manually it will work fine but if i do this through GUI it Readme.package.creation file will not take product type. From python null value will be sent.
Please help to solve my issue.
My code is:

```
      subprocess.call("sed -i '/export PRODUCT/d' .bashrc", shell=True)
      subprocess.call("sed -i '/export BOARD=TYpe/ a\ export PRODUCT=product1' .bashrc", shell=True)
      os.chdir("/home/x/y/z")
      subprocess.call("make clean", shell=True)
      os.chdir("/home/x/main/src/package")
      subprocess.call("sed -i 's/re.build -f -gui -p all/re.build -gui -p all -svn no/' README.package.creation", shell=True)
      subprocess.call("gksu debian", shell=True)
      subprocess.Popen("xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"./README.package.creation -u %s\";sleep 10'" % (str(u_name)),shell=True)
```

How to do after that I have to follow same procedure for Product 2 also

EDIT:
How about os.environ in python?
I have tried to change with os.putenv and then os.environ seems like it doesnot work fine.

Comment: Your `~/.bashrc` should be interesting.

Comment: @devnull: not mine it is, my companies:)

Comment: I think you don't need open a new terminal, you can `source ~/.bashrc`. But I don't understand your problem: you want create a debian package but you want to use ~/.bashrc? It's very silly solution - think about: if any other man wants to create a package from your program - his/her package will different because (s)he doesn't use bash and use e.g. zsh?

Comment: @uzsolt if i use source ~/.bashrc it is not taking any effect on .bashrc and as it is for my company so here all use bash only

Comment: @nammu So, only for clarification: do you want to build debian package? If yes, I think the debian-package should independent from bashrc. If you want generate two version you can create two file or you can use conditionals. Or do I misunderstood you?

Comment: @uzsolt debian package is independent but the script which creates the debian package is checks for product type , and if i change in .bashrc file i have to start new session so that changes done in .bashrc to take effect that can be done by opening new terminal and run debian package creation script. As i am doin it through gui i suspect that i am missing or doing wrong somewhere

Comment: Ah, you need only a bash-variable! You can define in debian!
E.g. like this: `Product=product1 myscript`.

Comment: @uzsolt in debian file board _1765p1.deb(if product 1) else board_1765p2.deb.

Comment: Create two script and you don't need dirty tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  import OS
  os.environ['product']='product1'
  subprocess.call("make clean", shell=True)
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very simple, and so is the solution:.

In the `subprocess.Popen(...)`, change the call from:

```
subprocess.Popen("xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"./README.package.creation -u %s\";sleep 10'" % (str(u_name)),shell=True)
```

to:

```
subprocess.Popen("xfce4-terminal -e 'bash -c \"source ~/.bashrc; ./README.package.creation -u %s\";sleep 10'" % (str(u_name)),shell=True)
```

Essentially, you're asking `bash` to source the `.bashrc` file before calling the package creation command.

Another illustration:

```
sgulati@precise:~$ cat /tmp/1.sh
export A=100
sgulati@precise:~$ python -c "import subprocess
print subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'source /tmp/1.sh; echo \$A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()"
100
```

In this example, I declare the variable `A=100` in `/tmp/1.sh`, `source` it and then execute `echo $A`. Because of `source /tmp/1.sh`, the value of `A` is known when `echo $A` is executed.

Please note that the syntax I used in my example is the syntax from `python 2.7.3`, but the concept is pretty much identical, no matter how you go about it.